# Does a hard disk wear?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, physical-wear

I am running a server, and I moved it to a new partition and it became much faster. Now, after 1 month it's becoming slower. I defragment once a day. The server uses the disk a lot(about **10mb/second all the time for 1 month continuously**) and I'm scared that it weared out the disk... Do SSD's wear less?

The temperature stays at around 50C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer didn't address the comment that this was doing it after **1 month**.  Even a consumer-grade 'black' hard-drive would not simply 'slow down'.  You would have other indications of failing mechanics.

Moreover, using 'server-grade' hardware does not give you 'no worries' if data is managed incorrectly.

This is likely a data-management/organization issue or even a network issue, and not likely a physical hard-drive issue.  There are [indicators](http://hddscan.com/).

Also, if it's requiring constant traffic and access, consider a separate NAS device.
Most modern OS's manage fragmentation on their own, not requiring a system-impairing constant defrag routine.

Answer (score 3):

Bearings wear out, grease dries out, bad shutdowns cause head crashes.

Modern hard drives are a bit tougher than in the bad old days.

I start worrying at about six years for server drives that run 24/7

This is on drives spec'd out for server operation, if you're using server grade stuff you have no worries.

Comment: What could be slowing down my server, and why would changing the partition(not drive) fix it, I ran a scan for bad sectors but found nothing.